# Access token validation is not working in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core-2.0, okta

I am building one POC, tech stack is **Angular** as front-end + **dot net core** as a back-end and **Okta** as a **authentication** and **authorization** provider.

I am able to authenticate user using **Okta NPM package** in angular front end app.

Now I receive two tokens one is **Access Token** and another is **Id Token**.

Now I want to secure my .net core API with Access Token, so for each request i am sending the access token to the server.

I have added the below code in my startup file, and have added the **Okta.AspNetCore** NuGet package.

```
       services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =     OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddOktaWebApi(new OktaWebApiOptions()
            {
                OktaDomain = "https://dev-819187.okta.com",
                Audience = "api://default",
            });
```

which is not working.

Then i added this code

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddOktaWebApi(new OktaWebApiOptions()
                {
                    OktaDomain = "https://dev-819187.okta.com",
                    Audience = "{App clientId}",
                    AuthorizationServerId = null,
                });
```

with which i am able to validate the **Id Token** but the same code is not working when i send **Access Token** to .net core.

Then I checked these url’s:

1. https://dev-819187.okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
2. https://dev-819187.okta.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server

which are returning the two different **jwks_uri** i.e:

3. https://dev-819187.okta.com/oauth2/v1/keys —> openid
4. https://dev-819187.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys —> oauth

and checked the **kid** in both the urls.

The kid returned by the openId keys (3) is matches with the kid in my **Id Token** when i decoded it with online urls such as https://www.jwt.io.

but when i decoded the **Access Token** the kid in access token doesn’t matches with the kid provided by Oauth keys (4)nor in Open Id Keys (3) url.

This is strange, I have wasted lot of time in investigating this but no joy.

and the sad part is when i try to validate the tokens manually using **postman** and **/introspect url** it returns success for both the tokens.

Note: I have only one authorization server that is default one.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: how about using the JwtBearer extension : https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide

Comment: IssuerSigningKey = signingKey ?? what is signing key here is it kid if not from where i can get it?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?
I run into the same problem using AWS Cognito Token. We can verify by IDtoken but not AccessToken

Comment: Yes, I will update it here. You need to recheck the all the configuration carefully